# Does Facebook bar re-loads on every request?

Tags: html, silverlight, sockets, iframe

While browsing Facebook pages I was wondering if their bar loads on every request.
Using Firebug i discovered this is true, but my user experience on their site tells me is not.
I know that their bar use **position:fixed;** and **bottom:0px;** CSS style, is this the only trick they do ?

Other sites loads their all content using an **iframe** while keeping the bottom bar on the main page. This way the bar is not loaded on every request. An example is sentimente.ro, but you must be logged in to see the bar.

What I am trying to accomplish is a multiplayer Silverlight online games, with Sockets, and I would like to have a bar just like Facebook has, all tables (with games) will appear on that bar. Browsing on other pages should not alter my activity bar content, all games should remain active.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657093/facebook-status-bar) here at Stackoverflow.com .